# Google sheets importxml weird import - Can't get the correct path to elements

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get some data from this website `https://etfdb.com/etf/VOO/`with IMPORTXML. Unfortunately, I was not able to scrape a particular element of the page but rather I got data only from these two functions

```
=IMPORTXML("https://etfdb.com/etf/VOO","//*")
```

---

```
=IMPORTXML("https://etfdb.com/etf/VOO","/html")
```

I tried to see if the browser is only loading data through JS but after disabling it the site loaded correctly, so I don't think JS might be the problem here.

How come after running a simple function like this, I get an error saying the scraped content is empty?

```
//span[contains(text(),'Tracks This Index:')]/following-sibling::span
```

EDIT: added spreadsheet with desired output https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zn0fQwenYZo6u4jP0yZ7J-NCzyzRnqabR3CDUz8jP3E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In order to confirm your situation, can you provide the URL you want to use and the values you want to retrieve?

Comment: Added it also in the question https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zn0fQwenYZo6u4jP0yZ7J-NCzyzRnqabR3CDUz8jP3E/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Issue:

Unfortunately, the value cannot be retrieved with the xpath of `//span[contains(text(),'Tracks This Index:')]/following-sibling::span` from the HTML data of the URL. For example, even when `//span` is used, `#N/A` is returned. The reason of this issue is mentioned by [Rubén's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57845851/7108653).

#### Workaround:

Here, I would like to propose a workaround. Please think of this as just one of several answers. In this workaround, the value you want is retrieved from all values from `body`. Although each tag in the body cannot be retrieved, `//body` can be retrieved. And fortunately, the value you want is included in the value from `//body`. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Retrieve values from the xpath of `//body`.
2. Retrieve the value you want by the regular expression.

#### Sample formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IFNA(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A1,"//body"),"Tracks This Index: (\w.+)"))),""))
```

- In this sample, the cell "A1" has the URL of `https://etfdb.com/etf/VOO`.
- After the value of `//body` was retrieved, the value is retrieved by the regular expression.

  - The important point of this workaround is the methodology. I think that there are various formulas for retrieving the value. So please think of above sample formula as just one of them.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- If you use above formula for other URL, an error might occur. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)
- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [IFNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944)
- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: I'm trying to apply this method to scrape similar info from the same website. I'm interested in the "emerging markets" percentage under "market tier breakdown" on [this page](https://etfdb.com/etf/VXUS/). However, if I use formula `TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IFNA(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML("https://etfdb.com/etf/VXUS/","//body"),"Emerging Markets (\w.+)"))),"")) `, it returns `ETF` rather than the desired `29.29%`. I think the reason is that there are other instances of the string "Emerging Markets" in the page source. However, I don't know how to account for this issue using your method.

Comment: Ok, I think I've found a resolution.  The following formula will extract the desired percent `TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IFNA(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML("https://etfdb.com/etf/VXUS/","//body"),"Emerging Markets ([0-9/.]+)"))),""))`.  I think this works because there is only one string containing "Emerging Markets" which is also immediately followed by a number--even though, in the imported XML, there are several strings containing "Emerging Markets" followed by text.

Answer (score 1):

This is partial answer.

The problem occurs because `https://etfdb.com/etf/VOO/` isn't a valid `XHTML` file.

Some failures:

- Use of `<hr>` instead of `<hr/>`
- Use of `<br>` instead of `<br/>`

The above failures cause that `IMPORTXML` can't parse below sibling tags.